# ASP Drop Down List postback losing session state in Chrome and IE but firefox works perfect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ddl on my master page that is set to auto postback to retrieve data based on their selection. The values in the list are customerids and they have been setup as a session variable and once someone has selected which one, the code looks at session["selectedCustomer"] and populates the appropriate fields. Now the problem that I have run into, is when the auto postback goes through on Chrome or IE, it populates the fields and then the selected customer is set back to default which is "Please select customer" which has no value behind it. In firefox after the postback it populates the fields and then the drop down list stays on the selected customer.

```
    protected void ddlSelectedCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerSelected();

        Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "0; URL=" + this.ResolveUrl("~/AcesSetup/storefront.aspx"));
        try
        {
            ViewState["SelectedAccordionIndex"] = ((AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion)FindControl("MyAccordion")).SelectedIndex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

That is the selectedChanged event for my ddl

```
    private void CustomerSelected()
    {

        //clear the session variable
        Session.Remove("selectedCustomer");

        //user selected customer
        if (ddlSelectedCustomer.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            Session["selectedCustomer"] = ddlSelectedCustomer.SelectedValue;
        }

    }

    private void fillCustomers()
    {

        //save the value of the current selection to reselect later if still exists
        string origSelectedItem = ddlSelectedCustomer.SelectedValue;

        //check what role the user is in
        string usersRole = Roles.GetRolesForUser(Membership.GetUser().UserName)[0];

        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();

        switch (usersRole)
        {
            case "SalesRep":
                ddlSelectedCustomer.DataSource = DAL.Util.getSalesRepCustomers((Guid)user.ProviderUserKey);
                ddlSelectedCustomer.DataBind();

                break;
            case "BasicUser":
            case "Customer":
                ddlSelectedCustomer.DataSource = DAL.Util.getCustomersListForUser((Guid)user.ProviderUserKey);
                ddlSelectedCustomer.DataBind();

                break;
            case "Admin":
            case "SuperAdmin":
                ddlSelectedCustomer.DataSource = DAL.Util.getAllCustomersList(); 
                ddlSelectedCustomer.DataBind();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        //if user had a company selected, reselect it if it exists
        if (origSelectedItem != string.Empty)
            ddlSelectedCustomer.SelectedValue = origSelectedItem;
        else if (ddlSelectedCustomer.Items.Count == 1)
        {
            //if only one item in the list, select it
            ddlSelectedCustomer.Items[0].Selected = true;
        }
```

This what populates the drop down list. Also when Firefox does the post back the whole page does not appear to reload, with Chrome or IE the whole page will flash white and reload.. That to me seems like it has something to do with it. Because with Firefox the viewstate I have for my accordion works like it is supposed to, but again not with Chrome or IE.

If you have any help I would appreciate it, if there is anything I can clear up, or any code snipets I could provide I will do my best to update everything.

Thank you.

Comment: Why is the code appending a `Refresh` response header?

Comment: With out it the I can not get the information to populate

Comment: Are you redirecting to the same page or a different page? Why not use the `Response.Redirect` method?

Comment: same page, the drop down is on my master page, and on Firefox, the refresh, refreshes the nested page on the master page, for chrome and IE it does the whole page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected void ContentPlaceHolder1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["selectedCustomer"] != null)
            {
                ddlSelectedCustomer.SelectedValue = Session["selectedCustomer"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

---

```
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" OnLoad="ContentPlaceHolder1_Load">
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

---

You don't lose the session , you just clear the selection .so try to handle the `Load` event of your `ContentPlaceHolder` by setting the selected value by the stored session.

Comment: This makes sense, I wasn't 100% that the session was being lost, because the value of the default choice is set to null, and thats the value it was being told to look at since the ddl goes back to it. I applied your method you are suggesting, but it is now not loading results and just setting it to the default every time I have set up a break point and am seeing if theres something I can do to stop this. Thank you for your response.